# More than one dynamic sidebar

Tags: sidebar

I created 3 dynamic sidebars in my function.php file, everything went well, no problems. 
in a file named, sidebar-services.php, I have the following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing services
 *
 * @package Group Joosen
 */
?>

        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'service1')): ?>



        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>


<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'service2')): ?>



        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>

        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'service3')): ?>



        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
```

In my front-page.php I have:

```
<section id="services" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <div class="wrapper">

<?php get_sidebar('services');?>

        </div>
</section>
```

**Everything is working fine**, I only have the feeling this is not the right way. 
Is there any possibility that I can have all the **div classes** in the sidebar-services.php file? In that file I want to "ask" for my 3 sidebars with one if-statement, otherwise it will create the classes 3 times. Hope you understand guys

------EDIT--------
**Why is this not working? This is what I mean with "more compact code" **

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'service1' ) and (! dynamic_sidebar( 'service2' ))): ?>



            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase? I cant tell what your problem is, and I see no faults with your code ( though I would make slight alterations, but that's irrelevant to this question and deosnt help you )

Comment: @TomJNowell There is nothing wrong but I have the feeling it is written to complicated. I want to keep the classes away from my "page templates". So: I want one if statement for my 3 sidebars.